# Arrange for files created in a directory to belong to the directory's group

Tags: permissions, directory, group

How do I set permissions so that whoever creates any files or directories in /directory, the group owner should automatically be the same group owner of /directory? This is on RHEL.

Comment: Homework question?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with SGID.

So can read more on this here: http://linoxide.com/how-tos/stickbit-suid-guid/

**Example on how to actually do it:**

Implementation of SGID on directory:

```
# chmod g+s /test/
# ls -ld /test
drwxrwsrwx 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 03:12 /test

Now swich to other user and create a file in /test directory.

# su - roger
$ cd /test/
$ touch roger.txt
$ ls -l roger.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 roger   root 0 Mar  8 03:13 roger.txt
```